# 配信中の既存iPhoneアプリの更新について（2月1日のApp Storeの新基準）

Tags: ios, monaca, iphone, appstore-approval

いつもお世話になっております。
WEB上に詳しい情報が出ていないため、わかる方に教えていただきたく書き込みます。

「配信中の既存iPhoneアプリ」の更新申請について、
2月1日以降に新基準を満たしていない(64bitサポートしていない）新規アプリ申請はリジェクトされると発表がありましたが、
既存アプリの2月以降更新申請は、まだ32bitでも大丈夫なのでしょうか？

※WEB上には、配信中アプリは6月1日までの更新申請は32bitでも大丈夫と書いてあったり、
　　どちらも新基準を満たさないとNGとあったり、情報が錯綜しているようです。

というのも現在配信中のiPhoneアプリを、先方より急きょ改修依頼をされておりまして、
monacaのCordova 2.9でビルドいるため基準を満たしておらず、
新基準対応に時間がかかり先方期限に間に合わない可能性もあるため
どう回答したものか…と悩んでおります。

わかる方、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

確定的な回答を記述することは難しいですが、現在のところ、AppleとCordovaの公式から出ている情報をまとめさせていただきます。

### 新規提出の場合

以下のCordovaの公式ページを見てみてください。下記の公式情報によるとCordovaの64bit対応を含んだ最低バージョンはCordova3.4.1になっています。下記、公式ページによれば、Cordova 2.9ではApp Storeが求める64bit対応をサポートしていないことから、新規提出のアプリはリジェクトの対象になると思われます。

> The first version of Cordova to include 64-bit for iOS is 3.4.1. Therefore, to meet
>   these requirements of the Apple App Store, you should be using at least version 3.4.1
>   of Cordova before this February deadline.

[引用元]
http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/11/25/ios-64bit.html

### 更新の場合

Apple社の公式Newsに従うのであれば、アプリ更新のデッドラインは2015年6月1日まで大丈夫のようです。ただ、なるべく早めにCordova 2.9系からは脱却した方が良いと思います。

> December 17, 2014 As we announced in October, beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS
>   apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 
>   8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same 
>   requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode 
>   build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit 
>   and 64-bit code.

[引用元]
https://developer.apple.com/news/

Comment: Middleさま  
  
丁寧にありがとうございます。大変助かります。  
確かに、、早めにCordova2.9から脱却します。。  
  
今回は、取り急ぎ現状のままで修正しようと思います。  
発注されれば来月中にはAppStoreに申請できる想定なので、  
また審査結果を書き込みたいと思います。  
  
本当にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

有料会費メンバーには、12月8日づけで、確定的なアナウンスメールが入っています。

1　2月1日より、新規Appは、64bit対応とSDK iOS8.0以降でのビルドが必須。
2  既存Appのアップデートは、6月1日より、同じ条件が適用される。

Comment: kmugitaniさま  
  
ありがとうございます。なるほど、登録アカウントにメールが入っていたのですね。  
iOS Developer Programのアカウント自体は  
クライアントさんに取得してもらっているため、  
そちらのほうにはメールが送信されていたかもですね。  
  
ありがとうございます！大変助かります